# How to declare variable as per user choice?

Tags: java, variables, user-input

So, I was writing a Java program and made a method  create that accepted Object datatype variable.
Here is the brief look

```
class FILO
{
   ArrayList listFILO;
   public void create(Object input)
   {
      Class<? extends Object> type=input.getClass();
      if(type.isArray())
      {
        /*Problem starts here. I want to create an array with same datatype as
         input but I can't get my head around it.*/
       }
         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think generics might solve your problem, but maybe you are after something different here?

Comment: When posting here, learn to use code formatting. Another user fixed some of your post this time. You should still fix the indenting.

Comment: @BasilBourque (*yep it made my eyes feel bad*) -- l'd let him polish the format

Comment: Sorry, I would remember this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection, using [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html).

```
Array.newInstance( input.getClass(), length );
```

But trying to use reflection like this is usually a bad idea. You want to require the user to enter the type you are asking for, and then check that the user has entered the correct type.

Comment: This program may cause a lot of errors, and I had to create it as I needed a variable which followed First In Last Out. So I decided to create a class which would I then use to create a custom variable with the functions I need. If anyone has any other suggestions how to deal, then please do tell me. And sorry for the code, as I didn't had my computer and wrote the question on my phone